Should we burninate [class-names]?
The tag class-names has 79 questions in it, has no wiki or wiki excerpt, and is used for questions where the questions refer to different things. Running through the burnination criteria:

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No; while it may partially describe the contents of the question, the fact that it is ambiguous means it can never be a reliable way to tell what the question is about, or even what language the question is about.

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No, the names of classes are not relevant to programming questions. What someone chooses to name a class is a matter of opinion and has no bearing on whether the code will work (with the one exception of trying to use a reserved keyword for a class name, but I don't think we need an entire sub-tag beyond class just for this one case.

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No (see the first test above); since the tag is ambiguous and has no wiki information, it doesn't really add useful information. Especially when there is a much more popular umbrella tag class available.

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. The oldest question to use the tag (presumably the one that created it) used it in a subjective way: to refer to the concept of naming a class in a way that is long but still appropriate. However,  questions throughout the years have used it not only to refer to the programming construct known as a class, but also to the HTML attribute class (or the CSS version for the class selector), to the npm package by the name 'classname', to the similar concept className in React/JSX.

Furthermore, all of the use cases of class-names that I have found are already adequately covered by the existing tag class, css/html when about the HTML attribute or CSS selector type, or react for the className property in React. Thus, I suggest we burninate this tag.

Ditto for classname (624 questions) ?? Or merge/synonimize both with class tag??

@Paulie_D Oh snap, I somehow missed that one.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

@HansPassant Sounds like a case for "npm-classnames" rather than the generic "classnames".

Only one user in the list of top answerers has answered two questions in the tag; everyone else has answered one.  No user in the list of top askers has asked two questions.  It doesn't seem to be a tag in which anybody specializes.  Also, the newest question with the tag was asked on 2022-10-31.  It is not an active tag.

Retrieving the name of a class is on-topic, but it doesn't need its own tag. Example Java question using the tag, example Ruby question asking how to get the name of a class, but not using the tag.

"or even what language the question is about." about Criterium 1 is not a valid argument... Or you can start burninating also 'variables' 'string' 'integer' 'array' 'function' etc...

tl;dr: Probably, but please first suggest a few alternative tags to associate with the questions currently tagged class-names.

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?

Yes, these are questions about the names of classes, the naming of classes, or the field className.

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Class naming choices are on-topic for this site; so is web programming involving CSS and className fields.

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Depends on the question I suppose, but quite possibly.

That said, it is ambiguous and used to indicate different concepts in different questions.

"Yes, these are questions about the names of classes, the naming of classes, or the field className." These are different things, so it should be prefaced with no, not yes, because the "describing what it is" rule also contains the requirement of being unambiguous.

"Class naming choices are on-topic for this site; so is web programming involving CSS and className fields." This is incorrect; class naming choices are matters of opinion and thus explicitly off-topic. Web programming involving CSS is on-topic, but className is not about CSS, it's about React.

"Depends on the question I suppose, but quite possibly." Without examples or justification this statement has no weight/adds nothing to the post. It is a long-winded way of saying "maybe".

I don't see how this is an answer to the question. Should it have been a comment instead? I already mention in my question that the existing tag [tag:class] would be sufficient. For questions about HTML or CSS, [tag:html] and/or [tag:css] are sufficient. I will add that for the className property in React, [tag:react] is sufficient.
